# How to improve slicing of elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve day 5 of `AoC`. I was able to solve the first part. The objective of the problem is as below:

The rules are given in the form of the `data` variable below.

The crates begin in the same configuration:

```
    [D]    
[N] [C]    
[Z] [M] [P]
 1   2   3
```

Moving a single crate from stack 2 to stack 1 behaves the same as before:

```
[D]        
[N] [C]    
[Z] [M] [P]
 1   2   3
```

However, the action of moving three crates from stack 1 to stack 3 means that those three moved crates stay in the same order, resulting in this new configuration:

```
        [D]
        [N]
    [C] [Z]
    [M] [P]
 1   2   3
```

Next, as both crates are moved from stack 2 to stack 1, they retain their order as well:

```
        [D]
        [N]
[C]     [Z]
[M]     [P]
 1   2   3
```

Finally, a single crate is still moved from stack 1 to stack 2, but now it's crate C that gets moved:

```
        [D]
        [N]
        [Z]
[M] [C] [P]
 1   2   3
```

In this example, the CrateMover 9001 has put the crates in a totally different order: `MCD`.

Before the rearrangement process finishes, update your simulation so that the Elves know where they should stand to be ready to unload the final supplies. After the rearrangement procedure completes, what crate ends up on top of each stack?

Below is my code:

```
data ="""move 1 from 2 to 1
    move 3 from 1 to 3
    move 2 from 2 to 1
    move 1 from 1 to 2"""

    first = ['Z', 'N']
    second = ['M', 'C', 'D']
    third = ['P']
    stack_numbers = {1: first, 2: second, 3: third}
for i in data.splitlines():
    i = i.strip()
    temp = re.findall(r'\d+', i)
    res = list(map(int, temp))
    n = res[0]
    move_from = stack_numbers[res[1]]
    move_to = stack_numbers[res[2]]
    for i in range(n):
        a = move_from[i:]
        move_to.append(a)
        res[1] = move_from[:i]
        res[2] = move_to
print(first, second, third)
seq = first.pop() + second.pop() + third.pop()
print(seq)
```

Basically, I am trying to use slicing here. I am trying to slice the elements in range(n) from the given stack and trying to append them using slicing to the desired stack and remove them from the `move_from` associated stack. However, I am not able to achieve the expected result.

The expected output is as given in the problem description which is `MCD`. The actual output I am getting by running the above for loop is as below:

```
['Z', 'N', ['M', 'C', 'D'], ['M', 'C', 'D'], ['C', 'D']] ['M', 'C', 'D', ['Z', 'N', ['M', 'C', 'D'], ['M', 'C', 'D'], ['C', 'D']]] ['P', ['Z', 'N', ['M', 'C', 'D']], ['N', ['M', 'C', 'D']], [['M', 'C', 'D']]]
['C', 'D', 'Z', 'N', ['M', 'C', 'D'], ['M', 'C', 'D'], ['C', 'D'], ['M', 'C', 'D']]
```

What exactly do I need to change here? Also, what would be an effective way of doing it? Because my solution is a kinda brute force way.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to the colums and instructions parsing is the following. There are surely better ways but as long as it works...

```
with open('data.txt','r') as f:
        lines = [line.split(' ') for line in f]
instructions = [tuple(map(int,(line[1], line[3], line[5].strip()))) for line in lines[10:]]
cols = []
for n in range(9):
    col = []
    for line in lines[:8]:
        col.append(line[n].removesuffix(']').removeprefix('['))
    cols.append(col)
```

Example

input:

```
[S]                 [T] [Q]        
[L]             [B] [M] [P]     [T]
[F]     [S]     [Z] [N] [S]     [R]
[Z] [R] [N]     [R] [D] [F]     [V]
[D] [Z] [H] [J] [W] [G] [W]     [G]
[B] [M] [C] [F] [H] [Z] [N] [R] [L]
[R] [B] [L] [C] [G] [J] [L] [Z] [C]
[H] [T] [Z] [S] [P] [V] [G] [M] [M]
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

output:

```
[['S', 'L', 'F', 'Z', 'D', 'B', 'R', 'H'], ['', '', '', 'R', 'Z', 'M', 'B', 'T'], ['', '', '', 'N', 'H', 'C', 'L', 'Z'], ['', '', '', '', 'J', 'F', 'C', 'S'], ['', '', '', '', 'W', 'H', 'G', 'P'], ['', '', 'S', '', 'G', 'Z', 'J', 'V'], ['', '', '', '', 'W', 'N', 'L', 'G'], ['', '', '', 'R', '', 'R', 'Z', 'M'], ['', '', '', 'D', '', 'L]\n', 'C]\n', 'M]\n']]
```

Comment: I am using `3.8` and it gives error `col.append(line[n].removesuffix(']').removeprefix('['))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'removesuffix'`

Comment: thats cause `removesuffix()` and `removeprefix()` are support by python 3.10+
To make it work just use `.replace(']','').replace('[','')`

Comment: It gives the wrong answer.